# Rename all JSON keys - Java - Jackson - springboot

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have a springboot application and I receive a JSON structure (a pretty big JSON) which looks like below, for example. Every JSON attribute Key has HEADER_ and _SUFFIX as a prefix and suffix.

Is there a easier way to strip off the HEADER_ and _SUFFIX portion and just present the neater JSON, without having to iterate though the elements and renaming them individually?

Thank you very much!

```
{
    "HEADER_Products_SUFFIX": [
        {
            "HEADER_ID_SUFFIX": "123456456",
            "HEADER_Varitions_SUFFIX": [],
            "HEADER_Label_SUFFIX": "Sony",
            "HEADER_Location_SUFFIX": "Cali",
            "HEADER_Price_SUFFIX": 649.0,
            "HEADER_Sold_SUFFIX": true,
            "HEADER_Accessories_SUFFIX": [
                "bell",
                "button"
            ],
            "HEADER_OtherCollections_SUFFIX": [
                {
                    "HEADER_Key_SUFFIX": "THis is a key",
                    "HEADER_Label_SUFFIX": "This is a vlaue",
                    "HEADER_Attributes_SUFFIX": [
                        {
                            "HEADER_Key_SUFFIX": "This is a key",
                            "HEADER_Label_SUFFIX": "THis is a label",
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String objectAsString = jsonObject;
String replacedPrefix = objectAsString.replaceAll("HEADER_", "");
```

You can use regexp for replace.

Comment: You don't need replaceAll. replace is fully sufficient. replaceAll is one of the most misleading named methods in all of Java.